# Elasticsearch query not giving exact match

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

Am searching elasticsearch with the below match query, which is not giving me the exact match instead its giving some more irrevalant match also.

am using elasticsearch 6.2.3

Please find my query below

```
get items/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "code" : "7000-8900"
      }
   }
}
```

Please find the response am getting it from `match` query

```
7000-8900
7000-8002-WK
7000-8002-W
```

Comment: Try `term` instead of `match`

Comment: Am not getting any results in `term` instead of `match`

Comment: this is exactly the goal of elasticsearch ^^ search against tokens, keep in mind that your document fields are tokenized into words (tokens), search operation is made against these words (document and query).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of `match` you have to use [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) query, as the documentation describe:

> The term query finds documents that contain the exact term specified in the inverted index

So you have to change your query as follow:

```
get items/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "term" : {
         "code.keyword" : "7000-8900"
      }
   }
}
```

---

If you don't get any result there are two possibilities:

- The term searched is not what you think it really is (for example is not trimmed)
- The index has no explicit mapping and the automatic mapping didn't recognize the field code as a string.

---

Note: if the mapping is correct and code is a term field it is possible to use "code". If the mapping was automatic and the mapping recognize it as text you need to use "code.keyword"

Comment: No results with `term`

Comment: Check if there is some space or special char around code

Comment: You might need to use `code.keyword` with the `term` query and not just `code`

Comment: its working properly for other fields like `"name" : "product7265"`

Comment: yes it might be `The index has no explicit mapping and the automatic mapping didn't recognize the field code as a string.` ., what shall i do for this?

Comment: Probably name was mapped as keyword, while code as text

Comment: @Karthikeyan check the updated answer (thx @Val) and use code.keyword not code

Comment: Its works., but in some case i need to search like `"code.keyword" : "7000-8002-*"` this is not working. i just want to search anything ( * )

Comment: This is not a term (exact) search. In this case you need to use a wildcard query https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html

Comment: For elastic search 8.4 above query returns exact match only, 
How can i return results like mentioned in the question

Comment: The question was asking for exact matching. If you need a like or similar search this is not the question / answer for you @RahulKumar

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue with the match, so I tried to use term. But it is a bad practice. ES says, we should not use term for string matching.

If you specify the field as keyword, the match will do the exact match anyway.

If you haven't defined the field as keyword, you can still do the query like this:

```
get items/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "code.keyword" : "7000-8900"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: It worked. I checked my column mapping on which i was applying search. it was "text" and type was "keyword".

     {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                "term": {
                    "node_title.keyword": "5-Verify-Offhours"
                }
                }
            ]
            }
        }
    }

Answer (score 4):

You can try this method.This query return exact match record.

```
import json
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch('http://localhost:9200')
res = es.search(index="test_index", doc_type="test_doc", body=json.dumps({"query": {"match_phrase": {"name": "Jhon"}}})))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can also search exact with .raw:
get items/_search
{
   "query" : {
      "match" : {
         "code.raw" : "7000-8900"
      }
   }
}
```